# observation about false sharing

Tags: caching, false-sharing, dirtyread

I have an observation about false sharing, please look this code:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y; 
};

static struct foo f;

/* The two following functions are running concurrently: */

int sum_a(void)
{
    int s = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        s += f.x;
    return s;
}

void inc_b(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        ++f.y;
}
```

> Here, `sum_a` may need to continually re-read `x` from main memory
>   (instead of from cache) even though `inc_b`'s concurrent modification of
>   `y` should be irrelevant.

By Oracle's website I read this explanation:

> simultaneous updates of individual elements in the same cache line
>   coming from different processors invalidates entire cache lines, even
>   though these updates are logically independent of each other. Each
>   update of an individual element of a cache line marks the line as
>   invalid. Other processors accessing a different element in the same
>   line see the line marked as invalid. **They are forced to fetch a more
>   recent copy of the line from memory or elsewhere, even though the
>   element accessed has not been modified**. This is because cache
>   coherency is maintained on a cache-line basis, and not for individual
>   elements.As a result there will be an increase in interconnect traffic and overhead. Also, while the cache-line update is in progress, **access to the elements in the line is inhibited**.

My observation is simple:
if what i read is true, how can be possible that exist the problem about "dirty read" ???

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by the "dirty read" problem? Are you referring to a race condition?

Comment: no i mean: reading old values.